# unusual comparision result when using is operator

Tags: python

I'm trying to compare variables using `is` operator. Here's what I've done

```
def get_no():
    return 1234

a = get_no()
b = 1234
c = 1234
print(a is 1234) #False
print(a is b)    #False
print(b is c)    #True
```

`a is b` is expected to be `False` as both are pointing to different values. But, why is `b is c` returning `True` ?. Why is the function `get_no()` causing a difference here?

Comment: "I'm trying to compare variables using `is` operator.". Why?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python `is` tests for object identity, not value equality. Use `==` to compare values.

As for the example case, it's because of how Python treats some values under the hood. On my system, for example, the integer value of `5` is actually the same object, while `1234` is a different object. You can verify this using the built-in [`id`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id) function.

```
>>> a = 5
>>> b = 5
>>> a is b
True
>>> id(a)
25769987752
>>> id(b)
25769987752

>>> a = 1234
>>> b = 1234
>>> a is b
False
>>> id(a)
25770739272
>>> id(b)
25770390520
```

This may be because of some internal optimizations in Python and apparently can vary between environments.

The bottom line is, `is` shouldn't be used for value comparison for this very reason, even if it works "well" in some cases.

Comment: @Christian Added the relevant explanation.

Comment: Well, I'm very intrigued. When I do `b = $` and `c = $` for **any** integer (including `500`), I get `True`.

Comment: @Christian I did some testing. For me the only integers that result in `True` are -5 to 256, which proves the point that `is` is "unpredictable" (as far as common use goes) for value comparison and shouldn't be misused for that.

Comment: I just realized that in an interactive session the result is `True` only for integers from -5 to 256, but on a script it works for any  integer.

Comment: @Christian For me it is actually consistent using either REPL or a script, no difference. I improved on the answer with these findings.